# Export XML to CSV with simplexml in PHP

Tags: php, xml, csv

i need convert XML to CSV with PHP. I have done simple reading of nodes and attributes with simplexml_load_file to echo and saving with header, but I am looking for better solution. Any ideas? My actual code is here:

```php
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("$url") or die ("Chyba: faktura nenalezena!");
$soubor =  $xml['cislo'];
header("Content-Encoding: UTF-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"soubor.csv\""); 
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
echo "Kód zboží; Popis zboží; Jednotka; Počet; Kusová cena; Procento DPH; Částka; Částka s DPH; Sleva; Rema; EAN; P/N; Záruka; Číslo faktury; Datum faktury; Datum zakázky; Datum zaúčtování; Datum splatnosti; Kód zákazníka; Kód měny; IČ dodavatele; Název zákazníka; Reference; Kód odběratele; Název odběratele; Ulice odběratele; Město odběratele; PSČ odběratele; Země odběratele; Kontaktní osoba odběratele; Kód způsobu dodávky; Částka; Částka s DPH; Zůstatek; Kód externího dokladu; Platební podmínka; Variabilní symbol" . "<br>";
foreach($xml->children() as $zbozi) {
echo $zbozi['kod_zbozi'] . ("; ");
echo $zbozi['popis'] . ("; ");  
echo $zbozi['jednotka'] . ("; ");
echo $zbozi['pocet'] . ("; "); 
echo $zbozi['kusova_cena'] . ("; "); 
echo $zbozi['procento_dph'] . ("; ");
echo $zbozi['castka'] . ("; "); 
echo $zbozi['castka_s_dph'] . ("; "); 
echo $zbozi['sleva'] . ("; ");
echo $zbozi['rema'] . ("; ");
echo $zbozi->ext['ean'] . ("; ");
echo $zbozi->ext['part_number'] . ("; "); 
echo $zbozi->ext['zaruka_mes'] . ("; ");
echo $xml['cislo'] . ("; ");
echo $xml['datum'] . ("; ");
echo $xml['datum_zakazky'] . ("; ");
echo $xml['datum_zuctovani'] . ("; ");
echo $xml['datum_splatnosti'] . ("; ");
echo $xml['kod_zakaznika'] . ("; ");
echo $xml['kod_meny'] . ("; ");
echo $xml['ic_dodavatele'] . ("; ");
echo $xml['nazev_zakaznika'] . ("; ");
echo $xml['reference'] . ("; ");
echo $xml['kod_odberatele'] . ("; ");
echo $xml['nazev_odberatele'] . ("; ");
echo $xml['ulice_odberatele'] . ("; ");
echo $xml['mesto_odberatele'] . ("; ");
echo $xml['psc_odberatele'] . ("; ");
echo $xml['zeme_odberatele'] . ("; ");
echo $xml['kontaktni_osoba_odberatele'] . ("; ");
echo $xml['kod_zpusobu_dodavky'] . ("; ");
echo $xml['castka'] . ("; ");
echo $xml['castka_s_dph'] . ("; ");
echo $xml['zustatek'] . ("; ");
echo $xml['kod_externiho_dokladu'] . ("; ");
echo $xml['platebni_podminka'] . ("; ");
echo $xml['var_symbol'] . ("; ");
echo "\r\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is `fputcsv()`. It needs a file handle and takes care of escaping.

```
$handle = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
fputcsv(
  $handle, ['one', 'two', 'with " and ,']
);
```

Output:

```
one,two,"with "" and ,"
```

Additional arguments to the function allow you to define the separator and enclosure characters.

```
$handle = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
fputcsv(
  $handle, ['one', 'two', 'with " and ,'], ';', "'"
);
```

Output:

```
one;two;'with " and ,'
```

Comment: thanks ;) its working... but I have another problem. Output file have bad code page. Is possible convert output?

Comment: done with `fputs($fp, $bom =( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) ));`